# How is this floating menu implemented?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

What is this widget called (the one with the three buttons), anyone knows?

[image: Android browser screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

found something here, they call quickaction.

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

I am sure this will help!

Comment: This one is great. It's apparently made by the same person who wrote that blog post in Eli Konky's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the implementation in the framework sdk.
A full example should be in the contact part (if you click on the contact image).

It should be somewhere around here :
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/master/src/com/android/contacts

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not a quick, simple control.  Check out the framework source code for an example.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source project for that component:

http://code.google.com/p/devoquickaction/

Screenshots:

http://code.google.com/p/devoquickaction/wiki/ScreenShots